# Operadores lógicos

Tags: c#, operador

No entiendo por qué toma los operadores lógicos `||` como si fuesen `&&`. Ya que cuando imprimo en consola, el ciclo while termina de ejecutarse una vez que ambos HP son menores a 0.

¿Podrían ayudarme o sugerirme alguna otra opción?

```
static void Main ( string [ ] args )
    {
        Random rnd = new Random ();
        int ataque;
        int saludP1 = 50;
        int saludP2 = 50;
        string personaje1 = "Vikingo";
        string personaje2 = "Francés";

        //Pelea
        while ((saludP2 > 0) || (saludP1 > 0) )
        {
            ataque = rnd.Next ( 10, 20 );
            Console.WriteLine ( $"Turno de {personaje1} [HP: {saludP1}]" );
            Console.WriteLine ( $"{personaje1} ataca con {ataque} puntos a {personaje2}" );
            saludP2 -= ataque;
            Console.WriteLine ( $"La salud de {personaje2} ahora es de {saludP2}\n" );
            Console.WriteLine ( $"Turno de {personaje2}  [HP: {saludP2}]" );
            ataque = rnd.Next ( 10, 20 );
            Console.WriteLine ( $"{personaje2} ataca con {ataque} puntos a {personaje1}" );
            saludP1 -= ataque;
            Console.WriteLine ( $"La salud de {personaje1} ahora es de {saludP1}\n" );
        }

        if (saludP2 <= 0 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine ($"{personaje1} gana el combate!");
        }
        if ( saludP1 <= 0 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( $"{personaje2} gana el combate!" );
        }

        Console.ReadKey ();
    }
```

Comment: Supongo que quieres que el combate acabe en cuanto la salud de alguno de ellos llega a 0... tu bucle `while`: `while ((saludP2 > 0) || (saludP1 > 0) )` hará que la pelea siga mientras cualquiera de ambos tenga vida mayor a 0. Literalmente significa: "Mientras p2 tenga más que 0 **O** p1 tenga más que 0"... Prueba a cambiarlo por `while ((saludP2 > 0) && (saludP1 > 0) )`, así en cuanto cualquiera de las dos variables baje de 1 se saldrá del while. Es decir, no lo está tomando como AND, ya que precisamente ahí necesitas un AND y no un OR

Comment: Muchas gracias Adrián! Cambié los operadores como me dijiste y funcionó. Yo había entendido al revés. Soy novato en C#, pero por suerte siempre hay gente dispuesta a ayudar.